# AJAX not getting response from API

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am calling my API from a HTML page. On ajax call, API will return in json format. I have below ajax to get data. But on console.log when I am trying to print the data. It's not printing anything.

```
$("#submit").submit(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var postData = $('form').serialize();

  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: url,
    data: postData,
    dataType: "json",
    function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  })
});
```

Return from API:

> {"code":403,"message":"Empty Name","status":false}

Comment: Assuming the missing `success:` key is just a typo (as you'd get a syntax error and no request sent if it wasn't) then the issue is simply because your `postData` does not contain the `Name` field that the API is expecting. You need to debug why that may be.

Comment: Also assuming the missing `success:` is just missing, you should also add `error:function(error) { console.log("Error", error); }` - if the API is returning an actual `403 Forbidden Status Code` (as implied by the "return from API") and not a `200 OK` then it won't be hitting the `success:` even if it was there

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes, `success:` was a typo. Also postData has the `Name`. If I check from network, I am getting success from API. However, it's not able to print from console.log under the ajax function.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be missing the callback function $.ajax.sucess. Try this:

```
$("#submit").submit(function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        var postData = $('form').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: url,
            data: postData,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        })

    });
```

Comment: If this was the problem then the OP would have gotten a syntax error in the code, and the call wouldn't be made. I would surmise this issue is just a typo when writing the question.